# How to put java variable into JSON string?

Tags: java, json, web-services, variables, dynamic

I have some variables, the value is dynamic but in this example, I'll give the fixed value of each variable. How can I put the variable in JSON string and post it to the web service?

```
String date = java.time.Clock.systemUTC().instant().toString();
String uuid1 = "6f0be90b-db0d-1b03-8a14-aaa70a5d239d";
String uuid2 = "671d2db0-b0d3-2745-9f76-52c22255a4b4";
String val ="1589430997009_658";
```

And this is the JSON String, how can I replace currentDateTime and uuid1, uuid2, and urlDocument with the variables that I have

```
{
"resourceType": "Bundle",
"type": "transaction",
"meta": {
    "lastUpdated": "2018-04-13T08:29:35",
    "profile": [
        "http://ihe.net/fhir/tag/iti-65"
    ]
},
"entry": [
    {
        "resource": {
            "resourceType": "DocumentManifest",
            "type": {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "code": "MPQ",
                        "display": "MPQ",
                        "system": "2.16.840.1.113883.5.25"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "status": "current",
            "id": "1231010",
            "description": "DocumentManifest",
            "created": "{{currentDateTime}}",
            "masterIdentifier": {
                "system": "1.1.1.9.9",
                "value": "{{uuid1}}"
            },
            "content": [
                {
                    "pReference": {
                        "reference": "DocumentReference/170013"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "subject": {
                "reference": "http://xxxx-myedu.online:8081/DataGateway/fhir/dstu3/Patient/1.1.1.99.1.-.d8a08ddc-b1f1-4c86-9bc6-9203914d9e6c"
            },
            "source": "1.1.1"
        }
    },
    {
        "resource": {
            "resourceType": "DocumentReference",
            "id": "170013",
            "status": "current",
            "created": "{{currentDateTime}}",
            "indexed": "{{currentDateTime}}",
            "description": "XXXS_Softpath Report histo",
            "masterIdentifier": {
                "system": "urn:oid:1.2.3",
                "value": "{{uuid2}}"
            },
            "content": [
                {
                    "attachment": {
                        "contentType": "application/pdf",
                        "url": "{{documentUrl}}"
                    },
                    "format": [
                        {
                            "system": "DEMO_FORMATCODES",
                            "code": "image",
                            "display": "DEMO_FORMATCODES"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "context": {
                "period": {
                    "start": "{{currentDateTime}}",
                    "end": "{{currentDateTime}}"
                },
                "facilityType": {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "DEMO_HEALTHCAREFACILITYTYPECODES",
                            "code": "MP",
                            "display": "DEMO_HEALTHCAREFACILITYTYPECODES"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "practiceSetting": {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "DEMO_PRACTICESETTINGCODES",
                            "code": "1200",
                            "display": "DEMO_PRACTICESETTINGCODES"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "sourcePatientInfo": {
                    "reference": "#thepatient"
                }
            },
            "type": {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "system": "DEMO_TYPECODES",
                        "code": "11111-7",
                        "display": "DEMO_TYPECODES"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "class": {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "system": "DEMO_CLASSCODES",
                        "code": "11111-1",
                        "display": "DEMO_CLASSCODES"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "language": "en_US",
            "securityLabel": [
                {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "DEMO_CONFIDENTIALITYCODES",
                            "code": "N",
                            "display": "DEMO_CONFIDENTIALITYCODES"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "author": [
                {
                    "reference": "#1235555"
                }
            ],
            "custodian": [
                {
                    "reference": "#1236666"
                }
            ],
            "subject": {
                "reference": "http://xxx-mye.online:8081/DataGateway/fhir/dstu3/Patient/1.1.1.99.1.-.d8a08ddc-b1f1-4c86-9bc6-9203914d9e6c"
            },
            "contained": [
                {
                    "resourceType": "Practitioner",
                    "id": "1235555",
                    "name": [
                        {
                            "given": [
                                "Support"
                            ],
                            "family": [
                                "Administrator"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "resourceType": "Organization",
                    "id": "1236666",
                    "name": "XXX-MOL",
                    "identifier": [
                        {
                            "use": "official",
                            "value": "1.1.1.9.9"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "resourceType": "Patient",
                    "id": "#thepatient",
                    "identifier": [
                        {
                            "use": "temp",
                            "system": "urn:oid:1.1.1.99.1",
                            "value": "d8a08ddc-b1f1-4c86-9bc6-9203914d9e6c"
                        },
                        {
                            "use": "usual",
                            "system": "urn:oid:1.1.1.2.2.1",
                            "value": "PatID-101"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": [
                        {
                            "family": "Family-101",
                            "given": [
                                "Given-101"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "gender": "male",
                    "birthDate": "2020-01-01",
                    "deceasedBoolean": false
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

I already tried to replace it using replace function from String java, and also already tried to use JSON Object put, but it doesn't work. Can anyone give more suggestions? Thankyou

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: One way: 1. Parse the JSON String to its representative Java object. 2. Change the fields of this object as you desire. 3. Stringify the Java object back to a JSON String.

Comment: Please share your [research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/), your [attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) in the form of a [MCVE](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/), and why [it's not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) including error messages and/or stack traces per the help article [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how to read the JSON from a file, modify a field, and print the updated JSON to the console:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class GsonMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setPrettyPrinting()
            .create();
        byte[] jsonBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("./src/main/java/gson/data.json"));
        String json = new String(jsonBytes);

        Map<String,Object> result = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType());

        String date = java.time.Clock.systemUTC().instant().toString();

        List<Map<String,Object>> entry = (List<Map<String,Object>>) result.get("entry");
        for(Map<String,Object> item: entry){
            Map<String,Object> resource = (Map<String, Object>) item.get("resource");
            resource.put("created", java.time.Clock.systemUTC().instant().toString());
        }

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(result));
    }
}
```

I used your JSON string as the "data.json" file content. Here is the output:

```
{
  "resourceType": "Bundle",
  "type": "transaction",
  "meta": {
    "lastUpdated": "2018-04-13T08:29:35",
    "profile": [
      "http://ihe.net/fhir/tag/iti-65"
    ]
  },
  "entry": [
    {
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "DocumentManifest",
        "type": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "code": "MPQ",
              "display": "MPQ",
              "system": "2.16.840.1.113883.5.25"
            }
          ]
        },
        "status": "current",
        "id": "1231010",
        "description": "DocumentManifest",
        "created": "2020-05-18T02:17:05.274Z",
        "masterIdentifier": {
          "system": "1.1.1.9.9",
          "value": "{{uuid1}}"
        },
        "content": [
          {
            "pReference": {
              "reference": "DocumentReference/170013"
            }
          }
        ],
        "subject": {
          "reference": "http://xxxx-myedu.online:8081/DataGateway/fhir/dstu3/Patient/1.1.1.99.1.-.d8a08ddc-b1f1-4c86-9bc6-9203914d9e6c"
        },
        "source": "1.1.1"
      }
    },
    {
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "DocumentReference",
        "id": "170013",
        "status": "current",
        "created": "2020-05-18T02:17:05.274Z",
        "indexed": "{{currentDateTime}}",
        "description": "XXXS_Softpath Report histo",
        "masterIdentifier": {
          "system": "urn:oid:1.2.3",
          "value": "{{uuid2}}"
        },
        "content": [
          {
            "attachment": {
              "contentType": "application/pdf",
              "url": "{{documentUrl}}"
            },
            "format": [
              {
                "system": "DEMO_FORMATCODES",
                "code": "image",
                "display": "DEMO_FORMATCODES"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "context": {
          "period": {
            "start": "{{currentDateTime}}",
            "end": "{{currentDateTime}}"
          },
          "facilityType": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "DEMO_HEALTHCAREFACILITYTYPECODES",
                "code": "MP",
                "display": "DEMO_HEALTHCAREFACILITYTYPECODES"
              }
            ]
          },
          "practiceSetting": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "DEMO_PRACTICESETTINGCODES",
                "code": "1200",
                "display": "DEMO_PRACTICESETTINGCODES"
              }
            ]
          },
          "sourcePatientInfo": {
            "reference": "#thepatient"
          }
        },
        "type": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "DEMO_TYPECODES",
              "code": "11111-7",
              "display": "DEMO_TYPECODES"
            }
          ]
        },
        "class": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "DEMO_CLASSCODES",
              "code": "11111-1",
              "display": "DEMO_CLASSCODES"
            }
          ]
        },
        "language": "en_US",
        "securityLabel": [
          {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "DEMO_CONFIDENTIALITYCODES",
                "code": "N",
                "display": "DEMO_CONFIDENTIALITYCODES"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "author": [
          {
            "reference": "#1235555"
          }
        ],
        "custodian": [
          {
            "reference": "#1236666"
          }
        ],
        "subject": {
          "reference": "http://xxx-mye.online:8081/DataGateway/fhir/dstu3/Patient/1.1.1.99.1.-.d8a08ddc-b1f1-4c86-9bc6-9203914d9e6c"
        },
        "contained": [
          {
            "resourceType": "Practitioner",
            "id": "1235555",
            "name": [
              {
                "given": [
                  "Support"
                ],
                "family": [
                  "Administrator"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "resourceType": "Organization",
            "id": "1236666",
            "name": "XXX-MOL",
            "identifier": [
              {
                "use": "official",
                "value": "1.1.1.9.9"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "resourceType": "Patient",
            "id": "#thepatient",
            "identifier": [
              {
                "use": "temp",
                "system": "urn:oid:1.1.1.99.1",
                "value": "d8a08ddc-b1f1-4c86-9bc6-9203914d9e6c"
              },
              {
                "use": "usual",
                "system": "urn:oid:1.1.1.2.2.1",
                "value": "PatID-101"
              }
            ],
            "name": [
              {
                "family": "Family-101",
                "given": [
                  "Given-101"
                ]
              }
            ],
            "gender": "male",
            "birthDate": "2020-01-01",
            "deceasedBoolean": false
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice how the entry > resource > created field now contains a timestamp. You can use this logic as a template to populate the other fields. This is just a quick example, there are other ways you could do this such as creating one or more POJO classes to represent your data and using Gson to create instances of your classes populated with the data from the JSON.